# typeorm db connection hangs while the server is still up

Tags: node.js, express, typeorm

Recently, I have been running some load test to our express node js api, with typeorm. The test is very simple, i am using a loop to hit the get food endpoint 3000 times.

something like

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
   fetch("http://url/food").then(resp=>resp.text()).catch(err=>console.log(err));
}
```

I did get a lot of ECONNRESET error (socket hang up). But after that, I can no longer hit that endpoint. I can still hit index endpoint (which does not require any db connection). But other than that, the api call just hangs. I thought the server was down, but I can still access the index (no db connection) endpoint.

I guess it might be something related to typeorm db connection, maybe the dead api calls still hold the db connections. Has anyone seen similar behavior before? Any help would be appreciated.

index endpoint

```
const router = Router();
router.get("/", function(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  res.send("food index!!");
});

export default router;
```

food endpoint

```
const router = Router();
router.get("/", getFoodController);

export default router;
```

the getFoodController will issue typeorm db connection

When I check the log I saw a tons of

```
GET /food -- ms --
```

Comment: Could you post `getFoodController` code here?

Comment: That is reasonable. Because the connection pool between typeorm and database is limited, each query will take the connection thread from pool for query, and then realease  the connection until response returned. When the requests is greater than the connections that can be used, there will be stuck.